# Permission denied error with flutter_libserialport 0.2.3

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting error Permission denied error with flutter_libserialport  0.2.3. How to Solve?

```
availablePorts = SerialPort.availablePorts;
```

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following SerialPortError was thrown building Builder:
Permission denied, errno = 13